# RxJava 2: Why can't PublishProcessor subscribe to an Observable?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, stream-processing

I want to implement rather simple DAG in RxJava.

We have a source of items:

`Observable<String> itemsObservable = Observable.fromIterable(items)`

Next, I'd like to have a processor that will subscribe to `itemsObservable` and will enable to multiple subscribers to subscribe to it.

So I created:
`PublishProcessor<String> itemsProccessor = PublishProcessor.create();`

Unfortunately, this isn't possible:
`itemsObservable.subscribe(itemsProccessor);`

Why? What's the proper API to implement this kind of DAG?

Here's a diagram for demonstration:

[image]

Here's my (failed) try to implement this kind of DAG:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
Flowable<String> source = Flowable.fromIterable(items);

PublishProcessor<String> processor = PublishProcessor.create();
processor.doOnNext(s -> s.toUpperCase());

processor.subscribe(System.out::println);
processor.subscribe(System.out::println);
source.subscribe(processor);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `PublishProcessor` implements `Subscriber` while `Observable`'s subscribe method accepts `Observer`. You can convert your `itemsObservable` to `Flowable` and it will do the job.

```
    Observable<String> items = Observable.fromIterable(Arrays.asList("a","b"));
    PublishProcessor<String> processor = PublishProcessor.create();
    items.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
            .subscribe(processor);
```

Comment: I see, thanks. And is this the common way to implement this kind of graph?

Comment: By the way, I just changed it to `Flowable.fromIterable` (instead of using `toFlowable`)

Comment: If you can create Flowable from the beginning its even better, no unnecessary conversion. Yes its common if you want to have multiple subscribers to one source. Other way is using `.share` operator

Comment: Just another small (but crucial question): so I have `itemsFlowable.subscribe(itemsProcessor)`. How to really process the item before emitting it using `onNext()`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'before emitting it using onNext'? You have `map`, `flatMap`, `doOnNext` operators.

Comment: Ok, I know I'm kinda stretching my question but could you please explain why my code fails to work? (see post)

Comment: Rx types are immutable, you have to call `subscribe` on what was returned by `doOnNext`. `processor.doOnNext(s -> s.toUpperCase()).subscribe(System.out::println);`

Comment: Also your `doOnNext` will do nothing. Try `toUpperCase` with `map`. `processor.map(s -> s.toUpperCase()).subscribe(System.out::println);`

Comment: I'll open a new question since I don't understand the role of `PublishProcessor` at all